# How to access session object in aquarium gem for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, aop

Currently I'm developing a rails project and logging is required in this project, so I used aquarium gem for doing the trick.
But the problem is when printing a logging statement I must print which person who made this action, for example

```
include Aquarium::Aspects
include Aquarium::DSLMethods
class LoggerController < ApplicationController



Aspect.new :after, :calls_to => :index,:in_types => [ReadingsController] do |jp, obj, *args|
  joinpoint=jp.target_type.to_s
  write_logs_to_file( "Action => list of all readings is shown, By => #{User.find(session[:userId]).name}")
 end
end
```

The problem is that class logger controller has no access to the session object, the question is how to wrap around this problem ?

Comment: does the `obj` passed as an argument refer to the controller instance? If so you can access session as `obj.session[:userId]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @all in advance I've wraped around the problem by using the Thread object so my logger class looked like this

```
include Aquarium::Aspects
include Aquarium::DSLMethods
class LoggerController < ApplicationController
def current_user
Thread.current[:user]
end

def self.current_user=(user)
Thread.current[:user] = user
end


Aspect.new :after, :calls_to => :index,:in_types => [ReadingsController] do |jp, obj, *args|

  write_logs_to_file( "Action => list of all readings is shown, By => #{Thread.current[:user]}")
 end
end
```

where Thread.current[:user] is set during the sign_in function by the userName